# Use of HttpValidationStatus.IgnoreThisRequest

Tags: asp.net, caching

I am studying the cache invalidation mechanisms and came across the HttpValidationStatus.IgnoreThisRequest.

I understand, that when this is specified, ASP.Net is going to treat response as Cache miss.

Another point is that the dynamic value received in this response is not going to replace the existing cache, as a result subsequent requests are going to use the already cached result.

1. What is the use of such a mechanism?
2. Why would someone want to use the already cached result even after having the latest ones?

Answer (score 0):

The use of HttpValidationStatus.IgnoreThisRequest. is meant for cases when you don't want to show a cached page only for that request.

Example:

```
public void Page_Load()
{
  Response.Cache.AddValidationCallback(new HttpCacheValidateHandler(ValidateCache), null);
}

public static void ValidateCache(HttpContext context, Object data, ref HttpValidationStatus status) 
{
    validationstatus = context.Request.IsAuthenticated ? HttpValidationStatus.IgnoreThisRequest : HttpValidationStatus.Valid;
}
```

In this case I want to serve cached pages to everybody except for logged users.

Think about a cms: i maybe want that an editor see the just edited page and not the cached one.